# Ubuntu 14.04 system settings does not open, gnome-control-center does not start either

Tags: 14.04, system-settings, gnome-control-center

is there a workaround? I need to access keyboard settings and set some key-mappings

```
$ sudo gnome-control-center

(gnome-control-center.real:6589): Gdk-ERROR **: The program 'gnome-control-center.real' received an X Window System error.
This probably reflects a bug in the program.
The error was 'BadRequest (invalid request code or no such operation)'.
  (Details: serial 127 error_code 1 request_code 149 (RANDR) minor_code 8)
  (Note to programmers: normally, X errors are reported asynchronously;
   that is, you will receive the error a while after causing it.
   To debug your program, run it with the GDK_SYNCHRONIZE environment
   variable to change this behavior. You can then get a meaningful
   backtrace from your debugger if you break on the gdk_x_error() function.)
```

Comment: try to run it with:  `gnome-control-center`

Comment: @abu_bua it is giving me same error without sudo also

Answer (score 0):

Run it with `gksudo` (Read `man gksudo`). `gksudo gnome-control-center`.

Comment: Hi waltinator, it is popping up window to enter password for administrative tasks. When I fill the password and enter OK, window disappears and nothing is happens after that